# Resize Button Icons in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, button, icons, nav

I recently built a web app using jquery mobile sdk. Everything work's like a charm, but now i want to resize a navbar button, to fit the navbar, which has been resized to 44px instead of the 32px.
I used the following code to  create the button.

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="header-custom">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="refresh" data-iconpos="notext" id="refreshButton">Refresh</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
```

My aim is to resize the button (and also the icon! :) ) to fit again into the new custom header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a possibility to resize the icons! Have a look into the jquery.mobile.icons.min.css file. There are the icons defined as svg Strings. Copy the class you like to edit and write it into your own custom.css file. Now look for

```
width%3D%2214px%22%20height%3D%2214px
```

in the svg String and change the 14 to whatever you want! At the end of your new css class you might add an "!important" to the background-image to make sure, you override the existing jquery class!

If you want to resize the icon from an a element, you have to additionally add an extra class to it. (In this case, change the svg String to 50px)

```
.icon50px {     
    height: 50px !important;
    width: 50px !important;
    font-size: 13px !important; }

.icon50px:after {
    height: 50px !important;
    width: 50px !important;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -25px; }
```

Have fun ;)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, if you want to **keep the icon crisp**, you will have to do **custom icons**.
**See instruction**:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

Comment: Hello Simon, thank's for your answer. I already checked out the custom icons, but didn't get smarter through the docu. Do you know any good example sites for custom icons?

Comment: Just in case if i don't want to keep the icon crisp. How can i resize the icon? I achived to resize the button, but no the icon inside of it. Which call do i have to override?